# Replace referenceContainer or referenceBlock

Tags: magento2

When my custom product type displays, I want a whole new layout/view. I have the content area being removed by nothing shows when I add it back. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<referenceContainer name="content" remove="true" />
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customproductform" template="CustomProductForm::customproductform.phtml"></block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 2):

it won't work in the way you are doing it.
Once you set `remove="true"` on a container (or block) that container (or block) will be ignored.
`remove` doesn't work like a reset button. once you set it, you can start over. It stays in there forever.
You will have to remove all blocks from the container otherwise. unfortunately I don't know yet how to do that.

Comment: It says here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html

To replace:
To replace an element, remove it and add a new one.

So, maybe I have to add a new <container name="content">
??
I tried that though and it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried to do  <container name="content"> without removing it prior? In effect replacing it?